# Push notifications with firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm getting this error when i test with token which I got from firebase
Error -The request's Authentication (Server-) Key contained an invalid or malformed FCM-Token (a.k.a. IID-Token)

these are the codes that i used to get token from firebase.

```
async getToken() {
  let fcmToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('fcmToken');
  console.log("before fcmToken: ", fcmToken);
  if (!fcmToken) {
    fcmToken = await firebase.messaging().getToken();
    if (fcmToken) {
      console.log("after fcmToken: ", fcmToken);
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('fcmToken', fcmToken);
    }
  }
}

async requestPermission() {
  firebase.messaging().requestPermission()
    .then(() => {
      this.getToken();
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('permission rejected');
    });
}

async checkPermission() {
  firebase.messaging().hasPermission()
    .then(enabled => {
      if (enabled) {
        console.log("Permission granted");
        this.getToken();
      } else {
        console.log("Request Permission");
        this.requestPermission();
      }
    });
}`
```

But I got this Error 401 when I test with APNS & GCM Tester Online
https://pushtry.com/

Please may I have any methods to get push notification for react native android application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use postman. Make a post request to this url "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send".
you need to send an object like this:

```
{
    "data":
    {
        "title": "your title",
      "body": "your body"
    },
    "notification": {
         "title": "your title",
      "body": "your body"
    },
 "registration_ids" : ["czf_nv_t1JA:APA91bGOyY3lTSG9b7Nr71xVo_Xn5RrxOIOwVfnKDv2OBanQjx1eQQyqdM3PFOd1Pjapm_DWn1R327iDyEwEeXjflJ3DyaGFF4iXmqot-OsyDt-Iz99Lu3MZZTvOSFIPiYgiaGHP5ByO"]
}
```

and registration_ids is your token.Also you need to set a header for your request with key Authorization and it's value comes from firebase console.for finding that you can check this https://developer.clevertap.com/docs/find-your-fcm-sender-id-fcm-server-api-key

Comment: I have tested with postman and get the success message. But still i couldn't get the notification there on my android emulator.

{
    "multicast_id": 4969739746123198930,
    "success": 1,
    "failure": 0,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "message_id": "0:1566968957667332%3b9a518e3b9a518e"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: have you tested it on a real device?

Comment: Yeah. I have tested on real devices also.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in Authorization value is as per your firebase cloud messaging server key.
Reference link:- https://www.djamware.com/post/5c6ccd1f80aca754f7a9d1ec/push-notification-using-ionic-4-and-firebase-cloud-messaging

Comment: I have tested with postman and get the success message. But still i couldn't get the notification there on my android emulator. { "multicast_id": 4969739746123198930, "success": 1, "failure": 0, "canonical_ids": 0, "results": [ { "message_id": "0:1566968957667332%3b9a518e3b9a518e" } ] }